# Weird Solr behavior with AND operator

Tags: solr

I'm performing 2 queries:

- name:"\#"
- name:"\#" AND userId:101

First query returns nothing and it's ok. But second query for some reason returns all records belonging to user.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet when looking at a query and not knowing what is going on is by using  the debugQuery option. It will show you what the string was entered in like as well as what it was parsed as.

There could be a lot of things going wrong.  "#" could be one of your stop words.  Also you could try sending a %23 since that is the url encoding for the # sign.